# MS SQL Server Management Studio - CDC not capturing data, CDC table is empty

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

I have a trial database that only has one table Users. I have followed a step by step tutorial (see below) that should enable CDC on this table. When I perform verification that the CDC is enabled, I receive a possitive response. However, when I perform any action on the table, the are no new records in the newly created cdc.dbo_user_ct table that should track the changes.

1. Am I missing something or is there some settings in the background that needs to be done?
2. If this for some reason would not work in my case, are there any alternatives how to see what is being done in the database? I prefer free versions.

I have followed these steps:

```
CREATE DATABASE Source_DB

USE [Source_DB];
GO
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'admin'
GO

CREATE TABLE Users
(
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName varchar(30),
LastName varchar(30),
Email varchar(50)
)

USE Source_DB  
GO  
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db  
GO

USE Source_DB  
GO  
  
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  
@source_schema = N'dbo',  
@source_name   = N'Users',  
@role_name     = N'admin',  
@filegroup_name = N'MyDB_CT',  
@supports_net_changes = 1  
GO 

INSERT INTO Users Values (1, 'Jorge', 'Ramos', 'ramos@yahoo.com')
INSERT INTO Users Values (2, 'Andrew', 'Strudwick', 'andrew@yahoo.com')
INSERT INTO USERS Values (3, 'Thomas', 'Tuchel', 'tuchel@gmail.com')

SELECT * FROM [cdc].[dbo_Users_CT]
GO
```

In all cases, the cdc.dbo_Users_CT table tracking the changes is empty.

Since there is not much documentation on the Internet, I havent tried almost anything (except restarting database, deleting and re-creating the database again, etc.)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61806/delayed-availability-of-historical-data-when-using-cdc

Comment: Going by that link, it seems like you need to make sure SQL Agent is running